# Error 1064 - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, I am receiving the following MySQL Error, but I cannot seem to put my finger on the place where I am going wrong. Please can you tell me the location of the error and how I can fix it?

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '"4ed2a19702d5feaa1eea283f", 'Pizza Hut', 'Pizza Place',
> 51.604771458125, -0.1884' at line 1

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `venues` (`fq_id`, `title`, `category`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `location`) ('4ed2a19702d5feaa1eea283f', 'Pizza Hut', 'Pizza Place', 51.604771458125, -0.18844127655029, '{\"address\":\"128 Ballards Lane\",\"lat\":51.604771458125,\"lng\":-0.18844127655029,\"postalCode\":\"N3 2PA\",\"city\":\"London\",\"country\":\"United Kingdom\",\"cc\":\"GB\",\"distance\":0}')
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `venues` (
  `fq_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location` text NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fq_id`),
  KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've missed the `VALUES` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO `venues` (`fq_id`, `title`, `category`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `location`)
VALUES
(...)
```

Comment: This guy is correct... That is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Mistake so stupid that I didn't see it xD, thanks!

Comment: I know how this place works @dsas, thanks, and as you're not a moderator, that's pretty irrelevant for you to say.

Comment: Sorry for any offence caused user43211. You were in the review list for users posting their first question, and I could see that you had commented on an answer that fixed your problem but had not accepted it.